# Run R script in parallel sessions in the background

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a script `test.R` that takes arguments `arg1`, `arg2` and outputs a `arg1-arg2.csv` file.

I would like to run the test.R in 6 parallel sessions (i am on a 6 core CPU) and in the background. How can I do it?

I am on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide a reproducible example so I am making one up.  As you are on Linux, I am also swicthing to [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which was after all *writtten for the very purpose of scripting* with R.

```
#!/usr/bin/env r
#
# a simple example to install one or more packages

if (is.null(argv) | length(argv) != 2) {
    cat("Usage: myscript.r arg1 arg2\n")
    q()
}

filename <- sprintf("%s-%s.csv", argv[1], argv[2])
Sys.sleep(60)   # do some real work here instead
write.csv(matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3), file=filename)
```

and you can then lauch this either from the command-line as I do here, or from another (shell) script.  The key is the `&` at the end to send it in the background:

```
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$ ../myscript.r a b &
[1] 19575
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$ ../myscript.r c d &
[2] 19590
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$ ../myscript.r e f &
[3] 19607
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$
```

The `[$n]` indicates how process how been launched in the background, the number that follows is the process id which you can use to monitor or kill.  After a little while we get the results:

```
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$ 
[1]   Done                    ../myscript.r a b
[2]-  Done                    ../myscript.r c d
[3]+  Done                    ../myscript.r e f
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$ ls -ltr
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 192 Jun 24 09:39 a-b.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 193 Jun 24 09:40 c-d.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 193 Jun 24 09:40 e-f.csv
edd@max:/tmp/tempdir$
```

You may want to read up on Unix shells to learn more about `&`m the `fg` and `bg` background s etc.

Lastly, all this can a) also be done with `Rscript` though picking arguments is slightly different and b) there are CRAN packages [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/package=getopt) and [optparse](http://cran.r-project.org/package=optparse) to facilitate working with command-line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the [doParallel](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/index.html) backend for the [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) package. The foreach package provides a nice syntax to write loops and takes care of combining the results. doParallel connects it to the [parallel](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) package included since R 2.14. On other setups (older versions of R, clusters, whatever) you could simply change the backend without touching any of your foreach loops. The foreach package in particular has excellent documentation, so it is really easy to use.

If you are going to write the results to individual files, then the result-combining features of foreach won't be of much use to you. So people might argue that direct use of parallel would be better suited to your application. Personally I find the way foreach expresses looping concepts much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

The state of art would be to use the parallel package, but when I am lazy, I simply start 6 batch (cmd, assuming Windows) files with rscript.

You can set parameters in the cmd-file

```
SET ARG1="myfile"
rscript rest.r
```

and read it from

```
Sys.getenv("ARG")
```

Using 6 batch files, I can also append multiple runs in one batch to be sure that the cores are always busy.

Comment: Same with bash, but better spawn support.

Comment: One can do much better than passing arguments via environment variables. Also note that OP wanted to args, and that Rscript has a capital R on all grown-up operating systems.

Comment: Agreed, but sometime it's the quick way out; otherwise I would not pass at all, but use "parallel". Which works under baby operating systems.